# Get array with all object specific values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
<db.collection>.find({ id : { $exists: true } })
```

this returns all documents with a `id` property.
how can I make it return an array with all the values of that id? Example:

```
{_id: ---, id: 21162 }
{_id: ---, id: 23712 }
```

returns: `[21162, 23712]`

**PS:** I thought about using a repetition structure that would go through all the properties and push an array, but I think it’s unnecessary and I think it’s not the best way to do this

Comment: use .map on the array and retrieve the id, endless examples on that online...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
let data = [
{'_id': '---', 'id': '21162' },
{'_id': '---', 'id': '23712' }
];

let result = data.map(item => item.id);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to achieve this:

The first one is to let Mongoose/MongoDB filter them, using the `projection` param:

```js
// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends').exec();
```

this is an example from the docs, here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

The other option is what Sabbir suggested, but it requires the whole list of documents returned by Mongoose to be loaded into memory and be processed one element at a time.